# Почему не работает метод firstWhere()?

Tags: php, laravel

Продолжаю разбираться с методами коллекции Laravel, на этот раз не понимаю, что делаю не так с firsWhere(). Есть переменная с коллекцией :

```
$coll = collect([
   ['name' => 'Regena', 'age' => null],
   ['name' => 'Linda', 'age' => 14],
   ['name' => 'Diego', 'age' => 23],
   ['name' => 'Linda', 'age' => 84],
]);
```

Есть переменная, которой я пытаюсь присвоить значение первого подмассива, удовлетворяющего условию фильтра метода:

```
$firstWhere = $coll->firstWhere('age', '>=', 18);
```

При попытке вывести переменную на экран через представление, получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю все то же самое, что в мануале от Laravel, но что-то не работает, пытался проверить дебагом,но не понимаю, что это значит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD: Я тестирую работу всех методов, так что в шаблон просто вывожу результат работы всех методов по порядку, код шаблона незатейливый, просто вывод переменной $firstWhere на экран, так же как я выводил почти все предыдущие методы:

```
    crossJoin: {{ $crossJoin }}
    <br>
    diff:
    [
    @foreach($diff as $num)
    {{ $num }}
    @endforeach
    ]
    <br>
    diffAssoc: {{ $diffAssoc }}
    <br>
    duffKeys: {{ $diffKeys }}
    <br>
    dump: {{ $dump }}
    <br>
    duplicates: {{ $duplicates }}
    <br>
    duplicatesStrict: {{ $duplicatesStrict }}
    <br>
    each: {{ $each }}
    <br>
    every: 
    @php
    var_dump($every);
    echo '<br>';
    @endphp
    except: {{ $except }}
    <br>
    filter: {{ $filter }}
    firstWhere: {{ $firstWhere }}
```

И всё работало, что изменилось сейчас?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в шаблоне какой код?

Comment: @u_mulder firstWhere: {{ $firstWhere }} просто вывод переменной на экран

Comment: Так ошибка же четко говорит что вы пытаетесь вывести массив. firstWhere вернёт массив с одним элементов ['name' => 'Diego', 'age' => 23],  и далее вы массив пытаетесь вывести как строку. Так делать нельзя.  {{ $firstWhere['age'] }} будет работать

Comment: И вот поэтому и надо приводить весь необходимый код.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov не понимаю, как это работает, я весь день сегодня так массивы выводил практически для всех методов, которые шли до этого, просто строкой, почему именно этот нельзя вывести?

Comment: @DmitriiSedov я обновил вопрос, не могли бы вы объяснить, от чего зависит возможность вывода на экран массива через переменную?

Comment: У тебя в дебаге написано что `$filter` это не массив, а объект типа `Collection`. При выводе такого объекта на экран, этот объект кастуется в строку, при этом вызывается метод `__toString` который для коллекции возвращает json-представление этого объекта. Для массива, естественно, никаких методов приведения к строке __не существует__.

Comment: Да точно, на память не помнил что firstWhere возвращает Объект коллекции. Ответ для Вадима. Данный метод возвращает новую коллекцию с отфильтрованными значением. Коллекция это класс который просто так нельзя вывести (см коммент @u_mulder) и читай про классы. Чтобы получить массив надо вызвать $firstWhere->all() и тогда всё будет работать. Для того чтобы понимать что в переменной не используй var_dump и прочую лабуду. В ларе для этого есть хелперы dump  и dd.   А так же директива \@dd и \@dump для дампа в шаблонах

Comment: Не надо вызывать никаких `all()`. `$firstWhere` уже массив, поэтому и не выводится через `{{ }}`. А я писал про переменную `$filter`. А про `dd\dump` очень верное замечание.

Comment: @DmitriiSedov спасибо большое, кажется начинаю понимать и за \@dump \@dd спасибо, про них я не читал ещё, буду пользоваться!

Comment: @u_mulder и вам спасибо,  теперь стало понятнее , буду разбираться дальше